# Feature or bug in the google url shortener depending on authentication method

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-url-shortener

If one calls the insert method while passing an api key on the request, then passing in a url like http://mostmedia.com/recent-projects  always returns the same shortened url.

But if you authenticate using OAUTH then you get a new unique id for every long url you pass in, even when they are the same.

You can see this behavior in the api explorer when you toggle on and off OAUTH authentication:

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert

I don't see this documented anywhere, so it's hard to know whether this is a feature or a bug, or how we can expect it to behave in the future.

Does anyone know the official google line on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior, see the section titled "Creating links when you’re signed in vs. signed out" on this doc: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/190768 coped below:

> ### Creating links when you’re signed in vs. signed out
>
> #### Signed in
>
> - Your links are automatically added to goo.gl where you can track their
>     use.
> - **A unique short URL is created each time a long URL is shortened.**
>
> #### Signed out
>
> - Your links won’t show up on your goo.gl page.
> - The same short URL is
>     reused each time a long URL is shortened by you or someone else.

That doc refers to the consumer product, but the behavior applies to the API as well.  OAuth authentication is the API equivalent of being signed-in.

The reason a new short URL is returned on each call is so you can utilise multiple short-urls for tracking purposes.

Comment: That post doesn't seem to mention the behavior I'm talking about, depending on authentication type it either does or does not return the same shortened url.  Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: See the bit under "Creating links when you’re signed in vs. signed out" where it says "A unique short URL is created each time a long URL is shortened.".  While that doc refers to the consumer product, it maps to the API functionality.  Using OAuth is the API equivalent to being signed-in.

Comment: I suppose when I'm using the api key it treats me as "not signed in" , though  I would think that I was.  You are right those links don't appear on my service account page.  Thanks for giving me some closure on this!

Comment: That's correct. API Keys (in the context of Google APIs) are more of a hint about your server's identity for things like quota enforcement, whereas OAuth is an actual authenticated session.